# Capturar rel de cada link clicado e ir acrescentando no value de um input hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho a seguinte estrutura, eu preciso criar algo "semelhante" a um carrinho de compras. Ao criar em um link eu preciso pegar o rel desse link e ir acrescentando no value do input hidden,mas eu não quero repetir valores, exemplo: 
Se cliquei no link de Produto 1, Produto 4 e cliquei em Produto 4 de novo, então eu quero que o value do input hidden receba os valores

> "produto1,produto4"

a estrutura da página é essa:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Produtos</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="produtos">

    <a href="#" rel="produto1">Produto 1</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto2">Produto 2</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto3">Produto 3</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto4">Produto 4</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto5">Produto 5</a>

    <!-- esse input recebe o rel de cada link clicado -->
    <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" value="">
    </form>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você pode colocar um `id` no input *hidden* para você poder identificá-lo melhor e enviar os valores.

```
<input id="produtos" type="hidden" value="">
              ↑
```

Depois você pode criar um evento `click` para pegar os valores dos links, inserir numa array e jogar para o input em forma de string (demais explicações no próprio código):

**Troquei o *hidden* por *text* apenas como exemplo para se poder visualizar os valores.**

```js
$(function(){
   
   var prods = []; // array para guardar os valores clicados
   // evento "click" nos links
   $(".produtos a").click(function(e){
      
      e.preventDefault(); // cancela o evento do link
      var p = $(this).attr("rel"); // pega o valor do atributo "rel" do link clicado
      // verifica se o valor já existe na array.
      // se não existe, adiciona com "push"
      // se exite, remove "splice"
      var indice = prods.indexOf(p);
      if(indice < 0) {
       prods.push(p);
      } else {
       prods.splice(indice, 1);
      }
      // converte a array em string com os valores separados por vírgula
      // e insere no input
      $("#produtos").val(prods.join(","));
      
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="produtos">

    <a href="#" rel="produto1">Produto 1</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto2">Produto 2</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto3">Produto 3</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto4">Produto 4</a>
    <a href="#" rel="produto5">Produto 5</a>

    <!-- esse input recebe o rel de cada link clicado -->
    <form method="post">
      <input id="produtos" type="text" value="" style="width: 500px;">
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, ajudou muito!

Comment: De nada amigo...

Comment: Sem querer abusar da sua boa vontade, mas vc poderia me informar por favor como eu faria para remover o valor do value caso eu clique em um link que já possui esse resultado no array? basicamente é como se fosse assim: clicou adicionou, clicou novamente removeu. Estou estudando JS mas ainda não cheguei nessas aulas mais avançadas

Comment: Subi uma alteração para remover caso já exista.

Comment: Ah, legal... já fez... valeu!